# Why can't I access my other form's widgets in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

So, I have the following code in my main window's Qt C++ form (under a button click slot):

```
    newform *nf = new newform(this);
    nf->show();
```

I want to be able to access a webview control I placed on the new form. After some research, I figured that calling nf->ui would be my best bet in order to gain access to all of newform's controls. So I went into newform.h and changed the *ui variable to public:

```
#ifndef NEWFORM_H
#define NEWFORM_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class newform;
}

class newform : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit newform(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~newform();

    Ui::newform *ui;

};

#endif // NEWFORM_H
```

Yet, whenever I try calling nf->ui, a dropdown menu doesn't appear and I still can't get access to my webview. When I type my code anyway and try to run, I get:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::newform'
error: forward declaration of 'class Ui::newform'
```

What's going on? Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ui::newform is an auto-generated class by Qt when adding a new Designer Form class to a project. Did you use the Designer Form class option or did you add that class manually?

Answer (score 2):

The errors are because you will need access to the ui class definition to call member functions and access the widgets it contains and that is a bad solution to cause such a dependency on that class internals.

So, don't try to access the *ui* (or the other members) directly, those are private and it's recommended that they stay that way, instead code the functionality you need into the *newform*  class and make that class do the work that you need to be triggered from mainwindow class, something like:

```
class newform : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit newform(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~newform();

//code a member function (or a slot if you need a signal to trigger it) 
//example:    
    void loadUrlInWebView(QUrl url);
private:
    Ui::newform *ui; //leave this private - it's not a good solution to make it public
};

//and in the .cpp file
void newform::loadUrlInWebView(Qurl url)
{
//you can access the internal widgets here
    ui->WEBVIEWNAME->load(url);
//do whatever you need here and you call this public function from other form
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can call `newform::loadUrlInWebView(QUrl)` in another class without instantiating an instance of the class or declaring it statically. I'm trying to find a good solution to this too. It also crashes randomly when I try making the `ui` static.

Comment: @JVE999 the instance is created, and showed, if the instance needs to be accessed from a class that didn't created it, then you need to decide if you need that one instance of a dialog or a new one? so first case: you just code a functionality to get a pointer to the already created instance from the one that created it, or second case create a new instance (but that is a different question, so maybe you should post a new question with your problem details)